# Unable to use display commands [gv, gs, etc.] in a Linux container on a Windows Host

Tags: linux, windows

I'm on a Windows Host and completely new to using Linux/containers, but to analyze the data I receive, I utilize a Docker container provided by my job. All of the commands within the container function flawlessly, with the exception of `gv/gs`.

Whenever I attempt to display a .ps file, I receive an error message stating `unable to display`.

While searching for a solution to this issue online, I come across numerous discussions regarding an X11 server and SSH connections, but I fail to see how they might be relevant to my problem.

It's important to note that I am not using SSH; rather, I am working within a Linux container.

Just to clarify, the problem is not the absence of `gv/gs` or related software for viewing postscript files. I have indeed installed the necessary software, but when I employ the respective commands, I consistently encounter the error message `unable to display`.

If anyone has any insights or suggestions regarding this matter, I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: can you check : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505647/how-does-docker-run-guis/505669#505669

Comment: @admstg Might be that I am using it wrong, but I can't seem to get it working using VcXsrv Xserver.

Comment: Does this help? [How to use GUI apps in linux docker container from Windows Host](https://medium.com/@potatowagon/how-to-use-gui-apps-in-linux-docker-container-from-windows-host-485d3e1c64a3)