# Does Wayland/Xwayland have a legacy x11 display socket?

Tags: x11, wayland, socket

I am trying to pass an x11 socket to a docker container as a volume so that it's applications can display on my screen. I am unsure of how to do this seeing as I am on wayland and I, a. do not know the location of the socket, and b. do not know how this forwarding might work.

Comment: Did you check this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505647/how-does-docker-run-guis/505669#505669

Comment: @admstg That is exactly what I am doing. I am wondering what the socket is for wayland.

Comment: My information might well be dating. For what concerns the socket… Could you check the existence of /run/user/whatevernumber/wayland-0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Xwayland you can use a display socket in the same path (/tmp/.X11-unix/). More information can be found [here](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/How-to-provide-Wayland-socket-to-docker-container).