# Running X Window/X11 application on a container

Tags: x11, docker

I have Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM centos:7 

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/app_config
WORKDIR /tmp/app_config
COPY app/ /tmp/app_config
COPY ./app_init.sh /tmp/app_config/

…
CMD ["./app_init.sh"]
```

`app_init.sh` has this.

```
#!/bin/bash
su - appuser -c /tmp/app_config/main &
```

When I run this container `docker run -it app/two:0.3.4` I get `Cannot open display :`

But, when I execute this container using `docker run --rm --privileged -ti -e container=docker -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup d568052b2e7c /usr/sbin/init`

It asks me to login and after that I can manually run this command to startup my application: `su - appuser -c /tmp/app_config/main &`, Just as in a VM.

Question is there a way to run X Window application without running a privileged container?

This deployment is supposed to run on a Kubernetes cluster, so running privileged containers isnt a possibility there. I understand that's not the best approach, but we have some strict requirements requiring this, hence looking for some possibility.

Comment: can you check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505647/how-does-docker-run-guis/505669#505669

Comment: @admstg Tried `docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  app/two:0.3.4`. still getting same error `Cannot open display :`

Comment: my bad, as your script use `su - user` it will probably loose the access to the .X11-unix socket. Why don't you use the USER parameter in Dockerfile to be sure the script is launched with this specific user and avoid to have a `su - user` in front of the real command ?